# Need a categorized post list for WordPress site, but having trouble with loops

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories

I'm working on a wordpress blog (_'s theme) and want to display all posts for every category in a menu that will be available on all pages

I am using the below code

```
<?php
        $cat_args = array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'child_of' => 0
        );

        $categories =   get_categories($cat_args); 

        foreach($categories as $category) { 
            echo '<h4 class="category" id="' . $category->name.'" >' . $category->name.'</h4>';

             $post_args = array(
              'numberposts' => 5,
              'category' => $category->term_id 
            );

            $posts = get_posts($post_args);

            foreach($posts as $post) {
            ?>
            <p class="category-post"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <?php 
            } 
            }
            ?>
```

This code will display and format the list exactly as I want it to.

The problems...

1.) On the index page this code will make my sticky posts disappear if it comes before the loop.

2.) On the single post page, nothing will display after the loop if the code comes after the loop.

Which would be fine as I can just use conditionals to display the code either or depending on the page, however...

3.) This code also makes it so that the single post loop will only display the content of the most recent post, but only when it comes before the loop, otherwise I'm back to problem 2.

I have tried following the code with wp_reset_postdata(); and wp_reset_query(); to no avail, and I cant figure out how to display everything correctly with the multiple loop tutorial in the codex.

also this is my single.php loop

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

and this is my index.php loop

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php wdh_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
   $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => 8, // specify category id here
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true ); 

    $myposts = get_posts( $args ); 

    foreach( $myposts as $post )
    {
      setup_postdata( $post );
      ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! The updated code is at the bottom of my post.